# Average calculator finding strange and incorrect numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an average calculator. This is my code for it:

```
var data = [];
var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
while (yesno) {
   var newdata = prompt("Enter a piece of data (must be a number)");
   data.push(newdata);
   var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
}
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
if (!yesno) {
   while (i < data.length) {
      total += data[i];
      i++;
   }
}
var average = total / data.length;
document.write(average);
```

It seems to take input well, however something goes wrong when it comes to calculation. It says that the average of 6 and 6 is 33, 2 and 2 is 11, and 12 and 6 is 306. These are obviously wrong. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: newdata taken from user is string..should be converted to Number !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is taking the input as string. Convert the input to floats before putting them in the array. I think its performing string additions like `6+6=66` and then `66/2 = 33`. Similar is the case of 2 and 2.

Answer (score 3):

You need to take a number, not a string value from the prompt.

The easiest was is to take an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for converting a number as string to a number

```
data.push(+newdata);
//        ^
```

Your first example shows, with `'6'` plus `'6'`, you get `'66'`, instead of `12`. The later divsion converts the value to a number, but you get a wrong result with it.

Comment: A little more information about why the behavior is the way it is wouldn't hurt.

Comment: And bonus points for an explanation for the last example: `'12' + '6' -> 306`

Comment: the last, i don't know ...

Comment: OP probably made a typo in the question, tested out the exact code, fed in 12 and 6, returned the expected result of 63.

Comment: I didn’t make a typo; I ran it again and got the same result (with broken code)

Comment: Last one is `6 and 12`. OP got the order mixed. `'6' + '12' = '612'` and `612 / 2 = 306`.